# Storing data from form into a database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, forms

It does not show any error when I run it but it does not store anything on the `bookstore_hw3` database on the table clients.

There is one more column on the table clients called `client_id` and is auto incremented. Is this the problem?

Can someone review this code and suggest what the problem is?

This is the HTML form:

```
<form  action="clientData.php" method="post">
First Name: <input type='text' id='client_fname' /><br />
Last Name: <input type='text' id='client_lname' /><br />
City: <select id='client_city'>
    <option>Please Choose</option>
    <option>Prishtine</option>
    <option>Mitrovice</option>
    <option>Peje</option>
    <option>Gjakove</option>
        <option>Ferizaj</option>
        <option>Prizren</option>
</select><br />
Gender: <select id='client_sex'>
    <option>Please Choose</option>
    <option>F</option>
    <option>M</option>
</select><br />
Username(3-10 characters): <input type='text' id='client_username' /><br />
Password(3-10 characters): <input type='password' id='client_pass' /><br />
<input type='submit' value='Submit' />
<input type="reset" value="Clear" />
</form>
```

This is the PHP code:

```
<?php
include('db_login.php');
// Connect
$connection = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password);
if (!$connection){
  die("Could not connect to the database: <br />". mysql_error( ));
}

// Select the database
$db_select = mysql_select_db($db_database);
if (!$db_select){
  die ("Could not select the database: <br />". mysql_error( ));
}
$fname = isset($_POST['client_fname']);
$lname = isset($_POST['client_lname']);
$city = isset ($_POST['client_city']);
$sex = isset($_POST['client_sex']);
$username = isset ($_POST['client_username']);
$pass = isset($_POST['client_pass']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO clients (client_fname, client_lname, client_city, client_sex, client_username, client_pass) VALUES ('$fname','$lname','$city','$sex','$username','$pass')";

mysql_close();

echo "Data stored on database.";
?>
```

This is the login code:

```
<?php
$db_host='localhost';
$db_database='bookstore_hw3';
$db_username='root';
$db_password='';
?>
```

Comment: You declare the insert statement in $sql but you never run the query, how do you expect anything to happen? Anyway note that you are vulnerable to sql-injections, use prepared statements instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is in the HTML code. PHP recognizes the data from the HTML form by the attribute `name` not `id`, so you should modify your HTML tags this way:

```
<input type='text' id='client_fname' name='client_fname' />
```

The second problem is with your PHP code.
Replace this part:

```
$fname = isset($_POST['client_fname']);
$lname = isset($_POST['client_lname']);
$city = isset ($_POST['client_city']);
$sex = isset($_POST['client_sex']);
$username = isset ($_POST['client_username']);
$pass = isset ($_POST['client_pass']);
```

with this:

```
$fname = isset($_POST['client_fname']) ? $_POST['client_fname'] : null;
$lname = isset($_POST['client_lname']) ? $_POST['client_lname'] : null;
$city = isset ($_POST['client_city']) ? $_POST['client_city'] : null;
$sex = isset($_POST['client_sex']) ? $_POST['client_sex'] : null;
$username = isset ($_POST['client_username']) ? $_POST['client_username'] : null;
$pass = isset ($_POST['client_pass']) ? $_POST['client_pass'] : null;
```

`isset()` only checks if the variable exists and returns true/false. In my code, the statement `isset(foo) ? foo : bar` checks if the variable exists and if yes, its content is returned, if no, then `null` is returned.

The third problem is that you are not executing your SQL query on the database. So add there also this:

```
mysql_query($sql);
```

Also your PHP code is vulnerable to SQL injection and should be fixed (you can read more about it in this post: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection))

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
$fname = isset($_POST['client_fname']);
$lname = isset($_POST['client_lname']);
$city = isset ($_POST['client_city']);
$sex = isset($_POST['client_sex']);
$username = isset($_POST['client_username']);
$pass = isset ($_POST['client_pass']);
```

All `isset` does is return a `1` (true) or `0` (false) so you are setting your data values to `1` or `0`. So it should be this instead:

```
$fname = isset($_POST['client_fname']) ? $_POST['client_fname'] '';
$lname = isset($_POST['client_lname']) ? $_POST['client_lname'] '';
$city = isset ($_POST['client_city']) ? $_POST['client_city'] '';
$sex = isset($_POST['client_sex']) ? $_POST['client_sex'] '';
$username = isset($_POST['client_username']) ? $_POST['client_username'] '';
$pass = isset($_POST['client_pass']) ? $_POST['client_pass'] '';
```

Note the format of `isset([something]) ? [something] : '';` which is a ternary operator which equates to `[check something] ? [if true do this] : [if false do this]`. It’s basically a simple `if`/`else` bit of logic but in one compact line.

Also, you set the query but never run it:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO clients (client_fname, client_lname, client_city, client_sex, client_username, client_pass) VALUES ('$fname','$lname','$city','$sex','$username','$pass')";
```

So that should be this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO clients (client_fname, client_lname, client_city, client_sex, client_username, client_pass) VALUES ('$fname','$lname','$city','$sex','$username','$pass')";
mysql_query($sql, $connection);
```

Answer (score 0):

The html attribute you use is wrong, you should use name attribute. For example:

```
<select name='client_city'>
```

And the code

```
$fname = isset($_POST['client_fname']);
```

Is wrong because the function isset return true or false if the argument is or not isset.

So the query inserted is

```
"INSERT INTO clients (client_fname, client_lname, client_city, client_sex, client_username, client_pass) VALUES ('false','false','false','false','false','false')";
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of isset function is incorrect.

You can use as shown below :

```
    $fname = "";                             // default for var for insert statement    
    if (isset($_POST['client_fname']))       // check if the field if not emprty
    {
        $fname = $_POST['client_fname']      // set the var for insert statement
    }
```

Using the same method with the other fields.